# Conditionally set TextView textStyle to italic in layout XML

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I wish to conditionally set the textStyle attribute of a TextView in my layout file. Setting "normal" or "italic" directly works fine, but how would I apply one of those two based on some boolean in my data binding?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="isComplete"
            type="boolean" />
    </data>

    ...

    <TextView>
        android:text="Some Text"
        android:textStyle="@{isComplete ? @string/textStyle_normal : @string/textStyle_italic}"
    </TextView>
```

When I try to run the above, the error is unclear, but my XXXBindingImpl class appears not to generate. I can update the text style programmatically in kotlin, but I was curious if there was a way to get this working in the view itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Binding Adapter to achieve this:

***BindingAdapter.kt***

```
@JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter("setTextCustomStyle")
    fun TextView.setTextCustomStyle(isNormal:Boolean){
        if (isNormal) this.setTypeface(this.typeface,Typeface.NORMAL) else this.setTypeface(this.typeface,Typeface.ITALIC)
    }
```

***xyz.xml:***

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{item.title}"
            setTextCustomStyle="@{isComplete}"
            tools:text="some text"/>
```

Comment: Still unsure why the string-based ternary I was trying doesn't work, but regardless, this does.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have set the "type" of the variable

```
 <data>
    <variable
        name="isComplete"
        type="com.example.YourClass" />
 </data>
```

In "type" you have to provide the name of the class with the package name for example "com.example.YourClass" as above example.

[This link might help you.](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions)

Comment: The type in this case is already set to boolean. The problem is with setting the textStyle.